# Microsoft Azure Active Directory Permission check implementation/RBAC

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am entering different users in USER schema of Azure AD and these users are supposed to have access to CRUD operations . But i also want that each user can only perform CRUD operations on its own record and not on someone's else .

Like a user can add /delete vehicles associated with him and but not for someone else.

Example we have 2 users Tom and Harry in USER schema. Now Tom is permitted to do view /update his records only but not Harry's .

Regards
Vikas

Comment: I'm not sure you have a question in there. Where are you storing the records that Tom and Harry create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have custom logic in your code that checks the user object ID against those that have been associated with the vehicles. E.g., a Vehicle object could have a List of object IDs and you can go if (vehicle.Contains(userObjectId). userObjectId is one of the claims in the token (oid in JWT).

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD does not currently support the level of customized RBAC at this point in time.

My suggestion was to create your own UX/API for users to view/modify this schema, implementing the authorization rules in my previous answer.